# setZoom and getZoom are undefined

Tags: fabricjs

I have created a canvas object but when I try to use getZoom() and setZoom it says that they are undefined.

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
new fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (omg){
    canvas.add(omg);
});

canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom()*1.1);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ckeck this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3TMA/662/

Comment: @ptCoder Thanks for share, please check my [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935775/capture-media-screen-min-width-and-insert-in-variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update fabric.js version to 1.4.13. You can download here: https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js

Zoom X 2:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var url = "http://serio.piiym.net/CVBla/txtboard/thumb/1260285874089s.jpg";
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (img){
    img.left = 80;
    img.top = 50;
    canvas.add(img);
});
canvas.renderAll();

alert(canvas.getZoom());

canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom()*2);
canvas.renderAll();

alert(canvas.getZoom());
```

I have made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tdzoygc4/1/

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes that's what i did....Though I have an issue after too much zooming in I canot add a circle on canvas

Comment: @Apostolos You've perhaps made a canvas that is too large. See here: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3293