# Canvas responsive media screen min-width - FabricJS

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, media-queries, fabricjs

I trying adjust canvas for each resolution, so I first using css and put medias screens for each resolution.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  #c {   -webkit-transform : scale(0.38);
-webkit-transform-origin : 0 0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qj3oyzs8/

It work for me, but all object not drag, resize or rotable properly.
One solution is apply zoomOut and zoomIn, eg:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3TMA/662/

Now I need help for know How capture resolution for open correctly canvas scale in the browser

---

**EDIT**

```
function screencan() {
   var widthscrencan = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;

/*

In if has to have the same scale the css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  #c {   -webkit-transform : scale(0.38);
-webkit-transform-origin : 0 0; }
}


*/
    if(widthscrencan <= 360 ) {
           // Zoom Out


 function zoomOut() {
        // TODO limit max cavas zoom out

        canvasScale = canvasScale / SCALE_FACTOR;

        canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR));
        canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR));

        var objects = canvas.getObjects();
        for (var i in objects) {
            var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
            var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
            var left = objects[i].left;
            var top = objects[i].top;

            var tempScaleX = scaleX * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
            var tempScaleY = scaleY * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
            var tempLeft = left * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
            var tempTop = top * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);

            objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
            objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
            objects[i].left = tempLeft;
            objects[i].top = tempTop;

            objects[i].setCoords();
        }

        canvas.renderAll();        
    }

    }               
 }
 window.onload = screencan;
```

It not work

Thanks for any help

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy !!! I got it :D

The only problem is that for a new resizing the browser move. It will be necessary to refresh the page, because window.onload = zoomIn;

Solution! I removed queryes screen of the css and:

```
widthscrencan = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width; // capture width screen onload
canvasScale = 1; //global  

   if (widthscrencan <=360){ 

      function zoomIn() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = .37;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

      canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
      canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

      var objects = canvas.getObjects();
      for (var i in objects) {
          var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
          var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
          var left = objects[i].left;
          var top = objects[i].top;

          var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
          var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
          var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
          var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

          objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
          objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
          objects[i].left = tempLeft;
          objects[i].top = tempTop;

          objects[i].setCoords();
      }


      canvas.renderAll();
      alert(widthscrencan+' function 360'); 

  }

   window.onload = zoomIn;
 }






   if ((widthscrencan >=361) || (widthscrencan ==768)){ 

            function zoomIn768() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = .45;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          for (var i in objects) {
              var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              var left = objects[i].left;
              var top = objects[i].top;

              var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

              objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
              objects[i].left = tempLeft;
              objects[i].top = tempTop;

              objects[i].setCoords();
          }


          canvas.renderAll();
          alert(widthscrencan+' function 768'); 


        }
          window.onload = zoomIn768;
    }

   if ((widthscrencan >=769) || (widthscrencan ==992)){ 

            function zoomIn992() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = .5;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          for (var i in objects) {
              var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              var left = objects[i].left;
              var top = objects[i].top;

              var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

              objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
              objects[i].left = tempLeft;
              objects[i].top = tempTop;

              objects[i].setCoords();
          }


          canvas.renderAll();
          alert(widthscrencan+' function 992'); 


        }
          window.onload = zoomIn992;
    }

      if ((widthscrencan >=993) || (widthscrencan ==1200)){ 

            function zoomIn1200() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = .9;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          for (var i in objects) {
              var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              var left = objects[i].left;
              var top = objects[i].top;

              var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

              objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
              objects[i].left = tempLeft;
              objects[i].top = tempTop;

              objects[i].setCoords();
          }


          canvas.renderAll();
          alert(widthscrencan+' function 1200'); 


        }
          window.onload = zoomIn1200;
    }


      if (widthscrencan >=1300){ 

            function zoomIn1300() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.01;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          for (var i in objects) {
              var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              var left = objects[i].left;
              var top = objects[i].top;

              var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

              objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
              objects[i].left = tempLeft;
              objects[i].top = tempTop;

              objects[i].setCoords();
          }


          canvas.renderAll();
          alert(widthscrencan+' function 1300'); 


        }
          window.onload = zoomIn1300;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead Of Using OR operation I used AND Operation and it worked perfect for me
here is the modified code of yours

Thanks. :)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.backgroundColor = "#Ffaafa";

var widthscrencan = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width; // capture width screen onload
var canvasScale = 1; //global  
var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.2;


window.onload = function () {
    
    var text = new fabric.Text('Text Here', { 
    left: 100, 
    top: 50 
    });
    canvas.add(text);
    
    if (widthscrencan <=360){ 
       zoomIn();
     }
    else if ((widthscrencan >=361) && (widthscrencan <= 768)){ 
          zoomIn768();
    }
    else if ((widthscrencan >=769) && (widthscrencan <= 992)){ 
          zoomIn992();
    }
    else if ((widthscrencan >=993) && (widthscrencan <= 1200)){ 
          zoomIn1200();
    }
    else  if (widthscrencan >=1300){ 
         zoomIn1300();
    }

};



function zoomIn() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = .37;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

      canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
      canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

      var objects = canvas.getObjects();
      for (var i in objects) {
          var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
          var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
          var left = objects[i].left;
          var top = objects[i].top;

          var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
          var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
          var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
          var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

          objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
          objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
          objects[i].left = tempLeft;
          objects[i].top = tempTop;

          objects[i].setCoords();
      }


      canvas.renderAll();
    alert('Display Area Width : '+widthscrencan+'px Function Called zoomIn'); 
  }
  
  
  function zoomIn768() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = .45;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          for (var i in objects) {
              var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              var left = objects[i].left;
              var top = objects[i].top;

              var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

              objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
              objects[i].left = tempLeft;
              objects[i].top = tempTop;

              objects[i].setCoords();
          }


          canvas.renderAll();
        alert('Display Area Width : '+widthscrencan+'px Function Called zoomIn768'); 

        }
        
        
        function zoomIn992() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = .5;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          for (var i in objects) {
              var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              var left = objects[i].left;
              var top = objects[i].top;

              var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

              objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
              objects[i].left = tempLeft;
              objects[i].top = tempTop;

              objects[i].setCoords();
          }


          canvas.renderAll();
          alert('Display Area Width : '+widthscrencan+'px Function Called zoomIn992'); 

        }
        
        
        function zoomIn1200() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = .9;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          for (var i in objects) {
              var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              var left = objects[i].left;
              var top = objects[i].top;

              var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

              objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
              objects[i].left = tempLeft;
              objects[i].top = tempTop;

              objects[i].setCoords();
          }


          canvas.renderAll();
          alert('Display Area Width : '+widthscrencan+'px Function Called zoomIn1200'); 


        }
        
        
        function zoomIn1300() {
          var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.01;
          canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

          canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
          canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

          var objects = canvas.getObjects();
          for (var i in objects) {
              var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
              var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
              var left = objects[i].left;
              var top = objects[i].top;

              var tempScaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempScaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempLeft = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
              var tempTop = top * SCALE_FACTOR;

              objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
              objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
              objects[i].left = tempLeft;
              objects[i].top = tempTop;

              objects[i].setCoords();
          }


          canvas.renderAll();
          alert('Display Area Width : '+widthscrencan+'px Function Called zoomIn1300'); 

  
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="550"></canvas>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
```